# permutation test sampling

Tags: intuition, permutation-test

In statistical inference, specifically while conducting hypothesis testing, we use permutation test, is there any reason why resampling is done without replacement (shuffle), what difference does it make when we using with replacement. In both cases we are breaking the relationship ?

Comment: By definition 'permutation' means 'shuffling'. So if you did sampling with replacement, it wouldn't be a permutation test. // However, bootstrapping is a different thing. In a nonparametric bootstrap you sample from the observed data _with_ replacement. // Both kinds of procedures use simulation (re-sampling), but the theories behind the procedures are somewhat different, so it is important to do sampling without replacement with permutation tests (and sampling with replacement when bootstrapping).

Comment: Thanks @BruceET: https://www.textbook.ds100.org/ch/18/hyp_introduction.html In this example authors use permutation test to see if child-birth weights have any real relationship with smoking, using shuffle (without replacment), I would get the conclusion (reject null) if I edit shuffle function by setting replacement=True (which essentially means bootstrap sampling). Is that a valid test to use, (shuffling with replacement) and arriving at the conclusion. Both methods break the relationship between weights and smoking status.  Is there any reason why one would prefer one over other here.thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Permutation test.** Suppose I am given the vectors `x1` and `x2` in R, each with $n = 20$ counts of flaws
in 20 specimens of a product, for two different production procedures. Data are tallied and plotted below:

```
table(x1);  mean(x1)
x1
1 2 3 
7 7 6 
[1] 1.95
table(x2);  mean(x2)
x2
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 1 4 8 4 1 1 
[1] 3

x = c(x1, x2);  g = rep(1:2, each=20)
boxplot(x~g, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Ordinarily, I might consider testing for a difference between the two population means
with a pooled or Welch two-sample t test or a two-sample Wilcoxon signed rank test. But the data are hardly normal, so I have doubts about using a t test, and the Wilcoxon test in R gives a warning message about
ties. So I wonder if I can get a reliable P-value from either procedure.

My concern is not that a pooled t test statistic is an unreasonable way to measure
the difference in sample means, but with the P-value, which depends on that statistic
having Student's t distribution with $\nu = 38$ degrees of freedom.

In order to perform a simulated permutation test, I will scramble the 40 counts at random between
the two groups (production procedures), and find the pooled t statistic. By doing this
repeatedly (say $m = 10\,000$ times), I can get a good idea of the true distribution of the t statistic. Then I can compare the value of the t statistic for the actual data to get
the P-value of the permutation test.

[By tedious combinatorial methods I might be able to
get the exact permutation distribution. In the permutation distribution, there are ${40\choose 20}$ possible ways to evaluate $T,$ not all leading to different results.  However, $m$ permutations of the data are enough for useful results.]

Details as we begin: The R function `sample` (without extra parameters) randomly scrambles the elements of its argument; two such permutations are show. For the original (unperuted) data, the observed value of the t statistic `t.obs` is $-2.99,$

```
sample(g)
 [1] 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1
[21] 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2
sample(g)
 [1] 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2
[21] 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1

t.obs = t.test(x ~ g, var.eq=T)$stat;  t.obs
        t 
-2.987193
```

From $m = 10\,000$ random scramblings, we get $m$ values of the t statistic, these make up our
simulated permutation distribution. Then the proportion of those $m$ values that
is more extreme than `t.obs` is the P-value of the simulated permutation test.

```
set.seed(325)
t.prm = replicate(10^4, t.test(x~sample(g), var.eq.=T)$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) >= abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.0054         # Simulated P-value
```

[image]

```
hdr = "Permutation Dist'n of t Statistic"
hist(t.prm, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v = c(-t.obs,t.obs), col="red", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

Although there are about 127 trillion possible permutations, because of the many
ties only $52$ uniquely different values of `t.perm' were observed.
Nevertheless, P-values from several runs had values between 0.0054 and 0.0082,
so there is no doubt about rejecting $H_0: \mu = 0;$ the two processes are giving
different results. Using a larger $m$ might result in slightly more consistent simulated P-values, but with the same decision.

**Nonparametric bootstrap confidence interval.**

Suppose I have $n = 100$ observations from an unknown distribution (for which I
believe the mean $\mu$ exists) in the vector `x`, which are summarized and plotted below.

```
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  50.17   59.66   69.89   70.45   80.69   90.94 
[1] 100          # sample size
[1] 11.29149     # sample standard deviation

hist(x, prob = T, col="skyblue2");  rug(x)
```

[image]

From the summary and  histogram, I suppose $\mu \approx 70,$ but I want a 95% confidence interval to give me some idea of the variability of that estimate.

If I knew the distribution of the quantity $\bar X - \mu,$ then I could find values $L$ and $U$ that cut probability 0.025 from the lower and upper tails, respectively, of that distribution, so that $P(L \le \bar X - \mu \le U) = 0.95.$ Then I could "pivot" to get the 95% CI $(\bar X - U,\, \bar X - L)$ for $\mu.$

Let $A_{obs} =\bar X_{obs} = 70.45203$ be the sample mean of the data as provided.

```
mean(x)
[1] 70.45203
```

Not knowing the distribution I enter the 'bootstrap world', re-sampling values of $\bar X$ to get realizations $D^*$ of $D.$ One iteration of this re-sampling goes as follows:
re-sample $n = 100$ values from the data `x` *with replacement,* to find $\bar X^*,$ temporarily use $A_{obs}$ as a proxy for unknown $\mu,$ and obtain
a realization of $D^* = \bar X^* - A_{obs}.$ [Notice that there is no use sampling
$n$ items from `x` *without* replacement; I'd just scramble the values in `x` to get the same *average* every time. In R, to do sampling with replacement, use the argument `rep=T` with the `sample` procedure.]

Obtain a few thousand, say $B = 3000$ such re-sampled values $D^*$ to get an idea of
the distribution of $\bar X - \mu,$ and finally estimate $L$ by the $L^*,$ the lower 0.025 quantile of this bootstrap distribution of $D.$ Similarly, use estimate $U$ by $U^*,$ the 0.975 quantile of the bootstrap distribution.

Now, emerging from the 'bootstrap world, $A_{obs}$ returns to its original role as
the observed sample mean of `x`, and use $\left(A_{obs} - U^*, A_{obs} - L^*\right).$

In the code for the 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI below, suffixes `.re` replace the `*`'s above to indicate re-sampled quantities. The code assumes vector `x` is already available in R. [It is always important to distinguish real data from re-sampled values because re-sampling is an *analytic device,* not a way to get additional information about the population.]

The resulting 95% nonparametric CI for $\mu$ is $(68.34, 72.60).$

```
set.seed(2021)
a.obs = mean(x)
d.re = replicate(3000, mean(sample(x, rep=T)) - a.obs)
UL.re = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
a.obs - UL.re
    97.5%     2.5% 
68.33898 72.60076
```

---

*Note:*
The R code below shows how the data vectors for the permutation test
and the bootstrap CI were simulated in R. Of course, in a real application
you would not know the true parameter values.

```
# permutation test
set.seed(123)
x1 = rbinom(20, 3, .7)
x2 = rbinom(20, 7, .4)

# bootstrap
set.seed(123)
x = c(rnorm(50, 60, 5), rnorm(50, 80, 5))
```